# Does the international community accept either nation’s claim in the US–Haitian Navassa Island dispute?

Tags: united-states, borders, territorial-dispute, haiti

[Navassa Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navassa_Island) lies between Jamaica, Cuba, and Haiti, and is claimed by both the United States and Haiti.  Have any other countries recognised either claim, or is the status of the international community neutral/indifferent?

Answer (score 4):

If [this paper](https://www.academia.edu/11665487/Navassa_Territorial_Dispute) on the topic (Navassa Territorial Dispute, by Fabio Spadi, IBRU Boundary and Security Bulletin, Autumn 2001) is anything to go by, the international community seems rather neutral/indifferent. Not even France seems to have lifted a finger.